# Android: Using setOnItemClickListener on ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a novice Android developer, using Android Studio and I'm attempting to develop my first app. I would like to remove an item from a list if it is clicked, but I'm getting the following exceptions/errors:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
                                                                                  at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:783)
```

When I click on the link "AdapterView.java:783" Android studio takes me to this following interface:

```
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> var1, View var2, int var3, long var4);
}
```

The code I'm trying to implement is:

```
public void removeItem(View view){
    /*
    Sample:
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
     */

    ListView vehiclesLst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vehicle_list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> vehicleAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_vehiclelist, vehicleList);
    vehiclesLst.setAdapter(vehicleAdapter);

    vehiclesLst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String vehicleItem = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            vehicleList.remove(vehicleItem);
        }
    });
}
```

I don't understand where the code is finding the *setOnClickListener* method. Does anyone know of any documentation that explains what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Why this?:

`String vehicleItem = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            vehicleList.remove(vehicleItem);`

You just:

```
VehicleList.remove(i);
```

Remove() method parameter would be the position of the array as an int and you are trying to pass a string.

More info:
[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html)

Comment: I was following an example I'd found. This was the way it was demonstrated. I'm not clear on what value in the ListView represents the position to be passed in.